# The sizeof and _Alignof value of a structure

Tags: c, sizeof, alignof

Which of the following are true in Standard C?

***(A)*** The `sizeof` a structure is equal to:

1. the relative address of its last member plus the `sizeof` **its last member**. (I know this *cannot* be true.)
2. the relative address of its last member plus the alignment value (as obtained by the `_Alignof` operator) of **its last member**. (This *cannot* be true also, because there are cases where the `sizeof` a type may be larger than its `_Alignof` value. See `long double` in 32 bit Windows GCC: `sizeof` is 12, `_Alignof` is 4.)
3. the relative address of its last member plus the alignment value of **the structure itself**. (This cannot be true also, as explained in the previous statement.)
4. the relative address of its last member plus the maximum of the last member's size and the  alignment value of **the structure itself**.
5. something else.

By *relative address* I mean the distance between the starting byte of its last member and the starting byte of its first member (or the structure itself) which can be obtained with the `offsetof` macro like this: `offsetof(struct st, last_member)`.

---

***(B)*** The `_Alignof` value of a structure is equal to:

1. the `_Alignof` value of its **member with the largest** `_Alignof` value.
2. something else.

---

Notes:

- I am not talking about specific implementations on specific environments, but rather how a **"Stardard C (C18)"**-compliant implementation should behave theoretically.
- `_Alignof` is the standard C operator and `alignof` is its macro synonym defined in `stdalign.h` header.

Comment: As for the first question then neither answer is correct.

Comment: `_Alignof` is the standard operator, `alignof` is its macro synonym defined in `stdalign.h` header.

Comment: Oh, it seems in the newest C Standard indeed there is _Alignof while in C++ there is keyword alignof.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: `alignof` is not a keyword; it is not in the list of keywords in C 2018 6.4.1 1 and was not in the list in earlier C versions. `_Alignof` is a keyword.

Comment: I believe there is nothing in the standard that says the `sizeof` a struct being anything in particular, except that it includes the sum of the sizeof its elements and any internal or final padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for A is “something else.”

The size of a structure must be at least the offset of its last member plus the size of that member plus enough padding bytes to make the structure’s size a multiple of its alignment requirement (which equals the largest alignment requirement of any of its members). A C implementation may add additional padding bytes in multiples of the alignment requirement, although I know of none that do.

The answer for B is the alignment requirement of the structure (its `_Alignof` value) equals strictest alignment requirement of its members (the largest `_Alignof` value of them).

In particular, note that C 2018 6.2.7 4 says “… Every valid alignment value shall be a nonnegative integral power of two.” Thus, if any alignment satisfies the strictest member alignment requirement, it satisfies each member alignment requirement, so it is sufficient.

Comment: Do you mean the answer to ***both*** questions is "something else"?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli: I neglected the second question. I have updated the answer.